# Html/PHP File Uploader in step 1, but uploading in last step

Tags: php, html, file-upload

so basically I have a multistep form with X steps.
In the first step, I offer a file upload form to the user.
This just behaves like a normal HTML file uploader:

- User selects file
- File Box, shows pathname

If the user clicks on "next" the file should not be uploaded.
If the user reaches the last step of the form, the files he/she has choosen in step-1 should be uploaded now.

I have no idea if this is actually possible. There are also a couple of problems

- The value from input type="file" gives something like C:\fakepath\filename.ext
- Saving the above in a session for later upload does not make sense.

How can I get the uploader to work in the last step?

Comment: you could use jquery to handle the form so that the page does not refresh but you can show/hide and move to different steps thus keeping the file data too

Comment: For now it is a drupal real multistep form.
If the above actually does not work, I might have to change to your solution, but I have to be completely sure that it either does not or does work.

Thanks for the comment

Comment: That's alright! if you need anymore help just let me know. As the answer below suggested using PHP $_SESSION might be of use :)

Comment: The session is no help, because right now the only information I can get from the input type=file via js is the fake name, nothing else.

On the server side I only get the required information if I upload the file right away. So there is nothing there to store in the session...

Comment: i do highly recommend looking into jquery for the form.

Comment: The whole project of a complex multistep form is almost already finished, so before changing the complete code I must be 100% certain, that it does not work.

So the questions remains: Is it actually possible or not to do this without changing everything into a jquery form?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25293/discussion-between-lockdoc-and-chriz)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is actually possible, and saving data between pages make sense, otherwise, how could you remember what he sets in the file input?

If it is a simple HTML page, I assume your are using PHP. Register files in a temporary variable or session, put it in a hidden input in the HTML code if you don't use session.

At the last step, set your files and upload it.

Good luck.

Comment: The problem is that I do not want to upload the files at step one.
The other problem is that I cannot get the real path of the file.
So how can I store the pathname?

Comment: The next problem will be, that the most (good) browsers do not allow a pre defined value in "type=file"-Fields, for security reasons.